# proxy web socket with node.js

Tags: node.js, websocket, proxy

i want proxy incoming websocket connections to another path, it can be `url` or `localhost:port`
i seen this code but i don't know what is `proxy`  and `endpoint` variables.
i think, we need a port to run server on it and a path to proxy connection to it, but i cant see them on this example.

```
var url = require('url');
var WebSocket = require('ws');
var HttpsProxyAgent = require('https-proxy-agent');

// HTTP/HTTPS proxy to connect to
var proxy = process.env.http_proxy || 'http://localhost:5000';
console.log('using proxy server %j', proxy);

// WebSocket endpoint for the proxy to connect to
var endpoint = process.argv[2] || 'ws://185.105.184.115:46607';
var parsed = url.parse(endpoint);
console.log('attempting to connect to WebSocket %j', endpoint);

// create an instance of the `HttpsProxyAgent` class with the proxy server information
var options = url.parse(proxy);

var agent = new HttpsProxyAgent(options);

// finally, initiate the WebSocket connection
var socket = new WebSocket(endpoint, { agent: agent });

socket.on('open', function () {
  console.log('"open" event!');
  socket.send('hello world');
});

socket.on('message', function (data, flags) {
  console.log('"message" event! %j %j', data, flags);
  socket.close();
});
```

Comment: You want to use a proxy but you don't what a  proxy is?

Comment: i know what is proxy ,but i cant understand this code

Comment: `proxy` variable stores a proxy server address,  `endpoint` variable stores a websocket server address